# Creating a generalized resource map without using strings?

Tags: c++, string, design-patterns, enums

Let's assume I want to create an object that will hold some arbitrary data.

```
// Pseudocode
class MyContainer {
    map<key, pair<void*, size>>;
}
```

The key in this case also identifies the kind of data stored in the void* (e.g an image, a struct of some kind, maybe even a function).

The most general way to del with this is have the key be a string. Then you can put whatever on earth you want and then you can just read it. As a silly example, the key can just be:

```
"I am storing a png image and the source file was at location/assets/image.png and today is sunday".
```

i.e you can encode whatever you want. This is however slow. A much faster alternative is using enumerators and your keys are then `IMAGE`, `HASHMAP`, `FUNCTION`, `THE_ANSWER_TO_LIFE`...

However that requires you know every single case you need to handle beforehand and create an enumerator for it manually (which is tedious and not very extensible).

Is there a compromise that can be made? i.e something that uses only one key but is faster than strings and more extensible than enums?

Edit:
The exact use case I am trying to use this for is as a generalized storage for rendering data. This includes images, vertex buffers, volumetric data, lighting information... Or any other conceivable thing you may need.

The only way I know to create "absolute polymorphism" (i.e represent literally any form of conceivable data) is to use void pointers and rely on algorithms to understand the data.

Example:

Say our key is a JSON string where the key of each element is the name of a field in a compact struct and the value is the offset in bytes.

E.g

```
  {
       m_field1: 0,
       m_field2: 32,
       m_field3: 128,
   }
```

Then to access any of the elements in the void* all you need to do is do symbol manipulation to get the number and then `ptr + offset`.

You can do the same with a set of unique identifiers (enums) and associated functions that get you the fields based on the identifier (hard coded approach).

Hopefully this makes the question less obscure.

Comment: `std::any` or `std::variant` perhaps?

Comment: How would using the hashed version of the bytestream of the data as the key be?

Comment: For both of your suggestions, they suffer from the problem of not being able to retrieve the type once stored. i.e this would be equivalent to just having the void* without a key.

Althought theya re itneresting suggestions int heir own right.

Comment: @Makogan: Of course you can't retrieve the type. A type is a compile-time construct; a value is *runtime*. You can't make the compiler know something that isn't known until runtime. So you either store one of a limited number of types (with a mechanism for extracting the actual type) ala `variant`, or you store something completely type-erased, and you're responsible for knowing via external means what type is actually stored, ala `any`.

Comment: @Makogan: "*This is however slow.*" Is it? Strings are just arrays of bytes; what about them makes them "slow"? In fact, using a `std::map` is almost certainly going to cause more overhead than using a decent identifier string type.

Comment: @NicolBolas A string, by virtue of being an array of bytes, requires more comparisons to determine equality and order in the average case than integers, for obvious reasons. Strings may, perhaps, be fast enough however assuming an application can solve the same problem with either strings or integers, integers should perform faster.

Comment: seems like you need 2 things from your key: (1) a unique identifier as, I assume, you could store more than one item of the same type and (2) a thing that clearly tells you the type. Would a `std::pair<string, std::type_index>` work as the key?

Comment: @NicolBolas You also seem to be assuming that I need to make the type available to the compiler, however, just like I can inspect the header of an image file buffer and realise it's a ppm  without the compiler being aware of any specific type so do i want to deal with my data. I.e I don't need g++ to be aware of which original type represented the data, I need my code to be able to fetch it and interpret it.

Comment: @OliverDain That would be a hybrid solution, which is essentially having both kinds of keys. It can work although if that is the key would the string not be used for key comparisons and thus be as slow as just having a string?

Comment: One thing you could do is use your wonderful all-descriptive strings, but have them stored in a `std::map<string,int>`: then the map in MyContainer gets keyed on `int`: whenever some code wants to operate on `MyContainer`'s map, it first checks for the key string in the former map, and if it's not there adds it with a unique int (e.g. the pre-insertion map size).  Likely, most code can cache the ints it cares about then do fast lookups in the `MyContainer` instances.

Comment: @TonyDelroy That is perhaps a good enough approach

Comment: @Makogan: "*A string, by virtue of being an array of bytes, requires more comparisons to determine equality and order in the average case than integers, for obvious reasons.*" You lack imagination. I once wrote an identifier string type that stored strings, but stored them as an array of unsigned integers, which it then used for comparison. I didn't care about the specific order, only that they *had* an order.

Comment: @Makogan: "*I don't need g++ to be aware of which original type represented the data, I need my code to be able to fetch it and interpret it.*" Then you're going to need to use some other language, because types *don't exist* at runtime. Types in C++ are *purely* a compile-time construct, a medium of exchange between your program and a piece of memory. Once your program gets compiled to assembly, all that's left is memory operations on bytes; everything that was your type no longer exists and cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, it;s not a lack of imagination, it doesn't matter which order of comparison you use, given 2 strings/array of bytes of length n with m equal values and m < n, it takes m checks to identify that that the values are different, this is slower than just using an integer.

You seem to not be understanding what I am saying, yes the g++ compiler enforces types at compile time, that's NOT what I am talking about.

Comment: I am saying that if `void* ptr` points to a struct of type `MyType` and I store the identifier `"MyType"`, The compiler won't be able to enforce any type safety and I am fully on my own, I don;t have any way to convert that pointer back into the underlying struct.

However I can infer from the string identifier the memory layout of the fields, for example, and access them by doing `ptr + field_offset`.

Comment: @Makogan: "*given 2 strings/array of bytes of length n with m equal values and m < n, it takes m checks to identify that that the values are different*" No, it doesn't. If I take 4 bytes of a string and put them in the four bytes of a 32-bit unsigned integer, how many comparisons does it take to determine that one such "string" is different from another? Precisely one: compare the two 32-bit integers. Now, do this for a fixed-size array, perhaps with 64-bit integers, and suddenly you can compare 32 characters with 4 actual comparisons.

Comment: That doesn't change my argument at all, all you have achieved is a constant time reduction by leveraging the fact that the hardware can execute 32 or 64 bit long comparisons in parallel. 

The asymptotic complexity hasn't changed.

Comment: @Makogan I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. If a type is all you need (and your suggestion of an enum suggests it is) then a key of `std::type_index` should give you the super-fast lookup you want plus it's extensible to new types. On the other hand if you need to allow multiple keys of the same type then a `pair<type_index, X>` where `X` is whatever your unique key is (e.g. a integer) also works. If neither of those work for you then I need some clarification about what you're trying to accomplish - perhaps update the question.

Comment: Can you show some usage examples?  From your description, `std::variant` seems like a good solution.